# Ubuntu 22 does not accept new routing table

Tags: networking, routing

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04 with Kernel 5.15.0 and I am unable to create a new routing table.

1. Create a new, custom routing table:

```
$ sudo cat /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
#
# reserved values
#
255 local
254 main
253 default
0   unspec
#
# local
#
1   rt2
```

2. reboot to make sure that the new table is known system wide
3. Add a new route to the newly create routing table `rt2`:

```
$ sudo ip rule add from 10.0.99.0/24 table rt2
```

4. Show the content of the newly create routing table `rt2` leads to an error:

```
$ sudo ip route show table rt2
Error: ipv4: FIB table does not exist.
Dump terminated
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Did you add any actual routes to the new table with `ip route`?

Comment: No I didn't. Would it be possible to give me a sample cmd? I would need to have this:

```
$ sudo ip rule add from 10.0.99.0/24 table rt2
```

Comment: There are many tutorials about routing and adding additional routes. How about [here](https://www.poftut.com/add-new-route-ubuntu-linux/) or [here](https://devconnected.com/how-to-add-route-on-linux/) to get started?

Comment: None of the links you posted give me any hints on how to add a new route to a custom (none default) routing table (in my case ```rt2```). Or did I miss something?

Comment: [This](http://linux-ip.net/html/routing-tables.html) is another link you might find helpful. But as an example: `ip route add table rt2 80.100.141.27/32 via 167.99.208.1 dev eth0 src 10.18.0.10`